# computing outfit mean-squares for each rating category in eRm (Rating Scale Model)

Tags: r

I am trying to replicate in R a published Rasch analysis performed with WINSTEPS. I am using the RSM function in the eRm package.

The authors of the published paper examine the item rating structure of an item set with a 5-point Likert response format.
One criterion they consider is that the outfit mean-squares are <2.0 for each rating category (from http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.424.2811&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

I managed to compute item outfit and infit following the example here: http://media.metrik.de/uploads/incoming/pub/Literatur/R/eRmvig.pdf. I  produced the Item Map via the plotPWmap function and I can see the infit t statistic for each category in this plot. But I could not find a way to compute outfit mean-squares for each rating category.

Is there a function that computes these? How can I get them as numeric output?

Many thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Let data_scored be a binary matrix of items and responses. Suppose you want to remove outfits for the person fit.

```
library(data.table)
library(eRm)

res <- RM(data_scored)
pp <- person.parameter(res)
pfit.pp <- personfit(pp2)
table.pp <- data.table(pearson.fit=pfit.pp$p.fit,
                        outfit=pfit.pp$p.outfitZ)
```

The values of table.pp$outfit will be the outfit mean squares. So now you can do:

```
table.pp.clean <- table.pp[outfit < 2 & outfit > 2]
```

And that will trim your table.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume, I am actually looking for the outfit mean-squares for each rating category for a rating scale model (not the person fit). Meanwhile, I checked with the package author and these are not available yet in eRm. I bought Winsteps and replicated the analysis in the same software. If anyone writes/knows of a function in eRm that obtains the outfit mean-squares for each rating category in a plot or table, would be great to make it available (you can also contact the author to include it in eRm, and authorship of the function will be acknowledged).